# Find absolute path of executable that can be run from CMD

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I need to find absolute path to `javaw` in my C++ application.
`javaw` can be run from command prompt & I can get its path using `where javaw` but I need the path in C++
How can I find the path to `javaw` in my C++ application?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c

Comment: @AlexanderBalabin: Unfortunately `where` command doesn't  return anything when is executed from `system` or `popen` !

Comment: I think the SearchPath API function does what you need.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yeah! Thats it! I've done something similar by myself at the end; But this is what i needed; Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is literally copy-pasted from the top answer to [How to execute a command and get output of command within C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c) and then call from `main` is added:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

std::string exec(char* cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = _popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while (!feof(pipe)) {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    _pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << exec("where javaw") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what it prints on my Windows 7 machine:

```
C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\javaw.exe
```

I guess you'd have to deal with the ambuiguities somehow, but I think I acheves why you're trying to do.

Comment: Although using `system` is very heavy ,I accept the answer because this works too. At the end I iterated through `PATH` environment variable & checked to find `java.exe` in each path;

Answer (score 0):

You could use a makro and compile with

```
-DJAVAW_PATH=`where javaw`
```

Comment: There is a `windows` tag on this question, so no command substitutions I guess

Comment: And it does not sound right to compile a path to an application into your program either